# Cassandra deploy cluster failure

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, cassandra, datastax, nodetool

I am trying to deploy Cassandra cluster on AWS. I followed instructions on http://datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installAMI.html
It looks everything is okay, but one node still getting 0 response. After initial script I ran

> cassandra-stress write

command on rest two nodes and everything was okay. When I tried to run

> nodetool status

command on failed node, I got this error message

```
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'.
```

I looked for cassandra service and it was down and when I started it and ran again I got this error

> error: No nodes present in the cluster. Has this node finished starting up?
>   -- StackTrace --
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: No nodes present in the cluster. Has this node finished starting up?
>           at org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner.describeOwnership(Murmur3Partitioner.java:129)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.effectiveOwnership(StorageService.java:3763)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.effectiveOwnership(StorageService.java:104)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
>           at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

and when I ran it again, I got the first error and cassandra service was down. I also changed /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml file. I set up seeds, listener address, rpc address, cluster name and token same as the rest of the cluster. Cassandra service goes down, when I run it again. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this node try to telnet to port 7000 of the other nodes. And from the other nodes try to do the same to this node. Most likely you assigned a different security group to this node and that is why it can't connect to the rest of the cluster.

> I set up seeds, listener address, rpc address, cluster name and token
>   same as the rest of the cluster.

P.S. I hope that you did not assign the same token to this node and the listener address you set to the node's own IP, not the other node's IP?

Comment: Nodes are in the same group. I want to avoid connection problems, so I set up only one rule in inbound traffic - allow all traffic from all adresses. I assigned the same token. Default on other is 256. On both. How can I assign right token for new node?

Comment: Yes I tried it from healthy node to another healthy node, but I got error
Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: What happens if you telnet from the failing node to the other nodes? Are you in EC2 or VPC? I suggest that you post your cassandra.yaml files (maybe excluding passwords and other sensitive info) here. Seems like there is a network configuration issue, since it can't see the other nodes. It can also be because of the seeds list mismatch, It can even be because the node can't resolve its name - there was a bug in the /etc/hosts file a while ago. Not sure if it's gone Post the hosts file too

Comment: It was the same error from failing node. I was in EC2. I deleted whole cluster and deployed a cluster again with the same configuration settings and it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

"Has node finished starting up" means that Cassandra is still starting. This could take a couple of minutes. Any other errors?

What does

```
nodetool status
```

Say from other nodes?

Comment: From other two nodes it displays 2 machines up, without this failed node. They are up and everything looks okay. When I waited for starting Cassandra, service goes down after few seconds. When I started it again I got the same errors.